# Firebase signInWithCustomToken in React Native

Tags: javascript, authentication, react-native, firebase-authentication

I use email and password for login at first login and I have a token with getToken() function, after I add localStoreage with AsyncStoreage.setItem("ACCESS_TOKEN",token). I want to refresh to app signup with token and I use signInWithCustomToken(token) but I have an error. its 'auth/invalid-custom-token' (The token you provided is not valid.). I can't login.

**DataStore.js**

```
onLogin: function (Data) {
    ApiRequest.login(Data)
        .then((authData) => {
            authData.getToken().then((token)=>{

                AccessToken.set(token)
                    .then(() => Actions.login.completed(authData));
            })
                    .catch((err) => Actions.login.failed(err))
        })
        .catch((err) => Actions.login.failed(err))
}
```

**ApiRequest.Js**

```
    login(data) { 
    // first.login data = (email.password) && after.login data=(token) 
    return new Promise((next, error) => {
        if (data && data.email && data.password) {
            this.firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email,data.password)
                .then((uData) => {;
                    next(uData)
                })
                .catch((err)=> error(err));
        } else {

            console.log("TOKEN:");
            console.log(data);
            this.firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(data)
                .then((authData)=>next(authData))
                .catch((err)=>{console.log("Error #232",err)})

       }
    });
}
```

**AccessToken.Js**

```
get(){
    return new Promise((next,error) => {
       if(this._accessToken) {
           console.log("LastToken");
           return next(this._accessToken);

       }
        AsyncStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN")
            .then((token)=>{
                if(token){
                    next(JSON.parse(token));
                }else{
                    error()
                }
            })
            .catch((err)=>error(err));
    });

}
set(token){
    this._accessToken=token;
    return AsyncStorage.setItem("ACCESS_TOKEN",JSON.stringify(token));
}
```

**Authenticate Listener**

```
actions.auth.listen(function () {
AccessToken.get()
    .then((token) => actions.login(token))
    .catch((err) => actions.logout());
 })
```

**Token**

> eyJhb...Ckz95w

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. firebase.auth().getToken() returns the Auth ID token. It is not a custom auth token. You cannot signInWithCustomToken using the Auth ID token.

Comment: thank for answer :) How can I login Auth ID token

Comment: I want to contuinue my Auth  and I think Auth ID token using for its